# How to use GenericArray with a limited range of length that can be detected at compile time?

Tags: generics, rust

For example,

```rust
struct Foo<T, N: ArrayLength<T>> {
    data: GenericArray<T, N>
}
```

I want the length of the data array to be limited within a range like `100` to `1024` bytes. Then, if the `Foo` is used like `let f: Foo<u8, generic_array::typenum::U8> = Foo {data: GenericArray::default()};`, it will cause a compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around a little with `typenum`, this works:

```
use generic_array::{ArrayLength, GenericArray};
use typenum::{IsGreaterOrEqual, IsLessOrEqual, Same, B1, U100, U1024, U99};

struct Foo<T, N>
where
    N: ArrayLength<T>,
    N: IsGreaterOrEqual<U100, Output = True>,
    N: IsLessOrEqual<U1024, Output = True>,
{
    data: GenericArray<T, N>,
}

fn main() {
    let f: Foo<u8, U100> = Foo {
        data: GenericArray::default(),
    };
    // Does not compile
    let f: Foo<u8, U99> = Foo {
        data: GenericArray::default(),
    };
}
```

The `IsGreaterOrEqual<M>` etc. traits, confusingly, are implemented even when `N < M`. You have to get their result by looking at the associated `Output` type. If it is `B1` or its synonym `True`, then `N` is indeed greater than or equal to `M`.

You might try to write a trait bound like `<N as IsGreaterOrEqual<U100>>::Output == B1`, but that's not possible. You can constrain an associated type either like in the code example, or by using a helper trait in `typenum`, `Same`: `<N as IsGreaterOrEqual<U100>>::Output: Same<B1>`.

Comment: You don't need `Same`, you can write this: `N: ArrayLength<T> + IsGreaterOrEqual<U100, Output = True> + IsLessOrEqual<U1024, Output = True>` (also, `True` is an alias for `B1`).

Comment: @FrancisGagné thanks, you're right! I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you both, FrancisGagné and nnnmmm

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want is Const Generics.

This feature exists in Rust, but it's still a work-in-progress. You can use it in nightly, and as far as I understand, there are some use cases that do work as intended.

Basically this allows you to have a generic type like this:

```rust
struct Foo<T, const N: usize> {
    // Here you can use `N` as a `const`. For example, to define the size of a `std::array`
}
```

Here are links to have or follow for this feature:

- The [const generics RFC](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2000-const-generics.html)
- The [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44580) for this feature in the rustc repo
- Latest [report](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44580#issuecomment-570191702) by varkor, the main implementor of this feature.

---

All in all, I think it's a shame that you can't use it in stable just yet. But great things take time to be built.

Check if you can use it. There are some `std` types that do use it today (and in stable because they have been audited to be sound and stable already). For example, [`std::array`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/array/mod.rs.html#106-114) uses it extensively since at least 1 year ago.

I hope this helps <3